# Changing a Tkinter Label from outside of the class

Tags: python, class, tkinter, label

I want to change the text in a label from outside of the class that is creating a Frame.

Here is the current code which I have cut down alot.

```
import tkinter as tk
import sys

class MyWindow(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent)
        self.label = tk.Label(self, text="Hello, world")
        self.label.pack()


root = tk.Tk()

run = MyWindow(root)
run.label.config(text = 'dddddddddd')


root.geometry('480x320')   
MyWindow(root).pack()
root.mainloop()
```

If I change

```
self.label = tk.Label(self, text="Hello, world")
```

to

```
self.label = tk.Label(root, text="Hello, world")
```

I end up getting a new label (I'm guessing a new instance of the label I created stacked on top of the last one).

Answer (score 0):

You never `pack` the `MyWindow` instance you created and called `run`, instead you `pack` a new instance in which you haven't changed the Label text.

Change

```
MyWindow(root).pack()
```

to

```
run.pack()
```